# How to resize UIView frame during button click?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5

I am using two button button1 and button2 and a view1,When I click the button2 the view1 frame should raised up to certain height and when button2 is pressed the view1 should be released to the normal position(original position), Can any one please help with the code.

```
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {

   [liftView setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 3.0, 200.0, 10.0)];
}
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {

   //here i need the view back to the original position
}
```

Comment: Can you show your codes? Put them into your question by editing it.

Comment: ok. i will add now

Comment: @raptor i added the code.

Comment: I notice you tagged old version of iOS. Are you using Auto Layout? If yes, the `setFrame:` won't work. You should adjust the auto layout constraints instead

Comment: no i didnt use auto layout..

Comment: Please read the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Auto Layout is not used, `setFrame:` can be used to adjust the layout as follow:

```
CGRect originalFrame;

- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender {
   originalFrame = liftView.frame;
   [liftView setFrame:CGRectMake(2.0, 3.0, 200.0, 10.0)];
}
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
   // set the view back to the original position
   [liftView setFrame:originalFrame];
}
```

Here I use a variable `originalFrame` to store the original frame size.

Optionally, you can wrap the `setFrame:` with `UIAnimation`, so that the layout change can be animated.